# Spring Cloud Gateway - Proxy/Forward the entire sub part of URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/) 2.0.0.M6 testing a simple gateway. I just want a URL to be forwarded to another URL with ** regex

*Example 1: /integration/sbl/foo/bar => localhost:4178/a-integration/sbl/foo/bar*

*Example 2: /integration/sbl/baz/bad => localhost:4178/a-integration/sbl/baz/bad*

So far I have written the following, but it only forwards to http://localhost:4178/a-integration/

```
 @Bean
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    String test = "http://localhost:4178/a-integration/";

    return builder.routes()
            .route("integration-test",
                    r -> r.path("/integration/sbl/**")
                            .uri(test)
            )
            .build();
}
```

How can I fix the above code to enable this behaviour?

**EDIT**

I tried the following based on response below

```
String samtykke = "http://localhost:4178/";

return builder.routes()

        .route("samtykke", r -> r
                .path("/gb-integration/sbl/**")
                .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/gb-integration/sbl/(?<segment>.*)", "/gb-samtykke-integration/${segment}"))
                .uri(samtykke))
        .build();
```

and I tried a GET http://localhost:4177/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/ and expected http://localhost:4178/gb-samtykke-integration/api/sbl/income/ back but it didn't work.

The output says:

```
2018-02-23 09:46:35.197 TRACE 6364 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.g.h.p.RoutePredicateFactory        : Pattern "/gb-integration/sbl/**" matches against value "[path='/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/']"
2018-02-23 09:46:35.198 DEBUG 6364 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: samtykke
2018-02-23 09:46:35.198 DEBUG 6364 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:4177/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/] to Route{id='samtykke', uri=http://localhost:4178/, order=0, predicate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.predicate.PathRoutePredicateFactory$$Lambda$245/1803714790@1d0042df, gatewayFilters=[OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory$$Lambda$247/485237151@77da026a, order=0}]}
2018-02-23 09:46:35.200 DEBUG 6364 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted gatewayFilterFactories: [OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@5c534b5b}, order=-1}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory$$Lambda$247/485237151@77da026a, order=0}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@396639b}, order=10000}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@a18649a}, order=2147483647}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@2b22a1cc}, order=2147483647}, OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@62573c86}, order=2147483647}]
2018-02-23 09:46:35.232 TRACE 6364 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.g.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter   : RouteToRequestUrlFilter start
2018-02-23 09:46:35.314 TRACE 6364 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.c.g.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter  : NettyWriteResponseFilter start
```

Comment: Use the rewrite path out set path filters

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you provide an answer with code?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the rewritePath functionality in your path filters, as specified by the documentation found here :

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#rewritepath-gatewayfilter-factory

Relevant parts :

> 5.12 RewritePath GatewayFilter Factory
>
> The RewritePath GatewayFilter Factory takes a path regexp parameter
>   and a replacement parameter. This uses Java regular expressions for a
>   flexible way to rewrite the request path.

```
spring:   
  cloud:
     gateway:
       routes:
       - id: rewritepath_route
         uri: http://example.org
         predicates:
         - Path=/foo/**
         filters:
         - RewritePath=/foo/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

> For a request path of /foo/bar, this will set the path to /bar before
>   making the downstream request. Notice the $\ which is replaced with $
>   because of the YAML spec.

In your example, that would look like :

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    String test = "http://localhost:4178";

    return builder.routes()
            .route("integration-test", r -> r
                    .path("/integration/sbl/**")
                    .filters(f->f.rewritePath("/integration/(?<segment>.*)","/a-integration/${segment}"))
                    .uri(test)
                  )
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I tried this, but it doesn't quite work. I get the following output `: Pattern "/gb-integration/sbl/**" matches against value "[path='/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/']"
RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: samtykke
o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:4177/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/] to Route{id='samtykke', uri=http://localhost:4178/, order=0`

Comment: Note I changed the paths a bit. The output says it got a match, but from the debug statement it looks like it only redirected to http://localhost:4178/ and not http://localhost:4178/api/sbl/income which I wanted. I tried doing a GET on http://localhost:4177/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/ but I didn't even get http://localhost:4178 back which is weird as it looks from the output like it got a match

Comment: I edited my question and added the comment in the question to be more clear

Comment: If you remove the trailing slash from your URI it will work.

Comment: I’m not sure why cloud gateway does not just ignore that slash... adding the slash gives unexpected behaviour, I’ll create an issue

Comment: It still doesn't work. It finds a match, but only redirects to my base URL `Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:4177/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/] to Route{id='samtykke', uri=http://localhost:4178, Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:4177/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/] to Route{id='samtykke', uri=http://localhost:4178,Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:4177/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/] to Route{id='samtykke', uri=http://localhost:4178`

Comment: https://github.com/boyenn/spring-cloud-gateway-example
If I run python -m SimpleHTTPServer 4178   and this sample , then browse to http://localhost:8080/gb-integration/sbl/api/sbl/income/ , the python server logs  "GET /gb-samtykke-integration/api/sbl/income/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: @ShervinAsgari Not sure if you get a notification if I don't do this

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow!

Comment: @ShervinAsgari how did You manage it to work? Could You please post the code?

Comment: @thorinkor He followed the example I posted above. ( github )

Comment: @thorinkor Yep, what Boyen said

Answer (score 21):

We were running a similar issue here, and although I agree with Boyen's response, it may be useful to point out that the **"uri" parameter ignores the "path" component of the URI**. This is not clear in the documentation (or I haven't found it at least), so I hope it helps others.

Suppose you want to redirect all the requests received at /foo to http://example.org/bar

For example: /foo/x/y/z --> http://example.org/bar/x/y/z

For instance this WORKS AS EXPECTED:

```
spring:   
  cloud:
     gateway:
       routes:
       - id: rewritepath_route
         uri: http://example.org
         predicates:
         - Path=/foo/**
         filters:
         - RewritePath=/foo/(?<segment>.*), /bar/$\{segment}
```

While this DOES NOT WORK as expected (it ignores /bar):

```
spring:   
  cloud:
     gateway:
       routes:
       - id: rewritepath_route
         uri: http://example.org/bar
         predicates:
         - Path=/foo/**
         filters:
         - RewritePath=/foo/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

Comment: Thank you for that remark about uri. Thtat saved my day

Comment: I also didn't find any docs on this. It is a bit infuriating that it doesn't  work in the more intuitive way. UGH.

Answer (score 3):

Please find below the two types of configuration with a full set-up. Both methods produce the same result.

#### Set-up:

- the gateway is running on `http://localhost:8090`
- a base path called `/context` serves as the entry point of the gateway
- a service called `my-resources` running on `http://localhost:8091/my-resources`. When `/my-resources` is invoked without parameters, it returns all resources. When it is invoked with a parameters it returns the resource with the corresponding `RID` (if any)

The gateway is configured so that all path variables (possibly none) transmitted to `http://localhost:8090/context/my-resources/` is forwarded to uri `http://localhost:8091/my-resources/`.

#### Method 1: using `application.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: route_id
        predicates:
        - Path=/context/my-resources/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/context/my-resources/(?<RID>.*), /my-resources/$\{RID}
        uri: http://localhost:8091
```

#### Method 2: using Java like configuration

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder routeBuilder) {
    return routeBuilder.routes()
            .route("route_id",
                    route -> route
                            .path("/context/my-resources/**")
                            .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/context/my-resources/(?<RID>.*)", "/my-resources/${RID}"))
                            .uri("http://localhost:8091")
            )
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed the ability to change contextPath when using rewritePath appears broken by changes in Spring Boot 2.3.X.  And  RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory.Config does not contain a field for passing a new contextPath in Hoxton.SR7+.

As a workaround I created a custom RewritePathGatewayFilter and used:

```
ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate().contextPath(newContextPath).path(newPath).build();
exchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, request.getURI());
return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
```