# URL path rewrite is not working as expected

Tags: java, url-rewriting, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have below piece of code to rewrite the path while routing the request to correct endpoint. However still the routing happening with full URL (original) without rewriting URL. **Similar type of path rewrite has been used for another endpoint, which is working fine.**

**Code**:

```
@Override
public Route.AsyncBuilder apply(PredicateSpec route) {
    return route
            .path("/api/out/**")
            .filters(f -> f
                    .removeRequestHeader("Cookie")
                    .filter(loggingGatewayFilter)
                    .filter(oauth2GatewayFilter)
                    .filter(this::filter)
                    .rewritePath("/api/out", "")
            )
            .uri(uri);
}
```

original URL: `http://external-url/api/out/xyz/data/getNext`

expected outcome: URL path will be rewritten to `http://external-url/xyz/data/getNext`

But still router is invoking the full URL.

What could be the issue here? **Any configuration in server side/endpoint (http://external-url) could cause this issue**?

**Spring cloud debug logs**.

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 47 45 54 20 2f 76 31 2f 6f 6d 73 2f 74 72 61 6e |GET /xyz/data/get|
|00000010| 63 68 65 73 3f 70 61 67 65 3d 30 26 73 69 7a 65 |Next?page=0&size|
|00000020| 3d 31 30 30 26 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 42 65 66 6f |=100&createdBefo|
|00000030| 72 65 3d 32 30 32 31 2d 30 31 2d 32 39 54 32 33 |re=2021-01-29T23|
|00000040| 25 33 41 35 39 25 33 41 35 39 2e 39 39 39 25 32 |%3A59%3A59.999%2|
|00000050| 42 30 38 25 33 41 30 30 26 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 |B08%3A00&created|
|00000060| 41 66 74 65 72 3d 32 30 32 31 2d 30 31 2d 32 39 |After=2021-01-29|
```

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865174/spring-cloud-gateway-proxy-forward-the-entire-sub-part-of-url , you will be able to figure out

Comment: @pradoshnair it is the same thing what I have currently.

Comment: can you try `f.rewritePath("/api/out/(?<segment>.*)","/${segment}"))`

Comment: @pradoshnair yes, already did. As per my understanding this has nothing to do with my code. I have few more routing with URL rewrite which is working fine. I could see spring cloud debug logs with correct rewriting. Feel like this has something to do with the endpoint.

Comment: what is the value in uri ? http://external-url ?

Comment: What's the value of "uri"?

Comment: Hey can you post some logs? You wrote "debug logs" but I didn't see too much there.